# Assigned multiple users to a 'task'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database-schema

Okay so I'm creating a task manager for my company. A user can assign assign a task to multiple other users. So I've though of 2 ways of implementing this.

This is my tasks table for option one (at least the columns that are important in this discussion ):

```
----------------------------------------------
|   id   |   assigned_to   | assigned_from   |
---------------------------------------------
|   1    |    1,3,6       |      4           |
 --------------------------------------------
|   2    |      1,4        |      2         |
---------------------------------------------
```

So here I pretty much just comma separate each user_id that is assigned to this particular task

Option 2:

```
----------------------------------------------------------
|   id   |   task_id   |   assigned_to   | assigned_from   |
------------------------------------------------------------
|   1    |   335901    |      1          |      4          |
 -----------------------------------------------------------
|   2    |   335901    |      3         |       4          |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|   3    |   335901    |      6         |       4          |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|   4    |   564520    |      1         |       2          |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|   4    |   564520    |      4         |       2          |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

So as you can see here instead of putting the assiged_to is's here I just create a task id which is a random number and then I can groupBy 'task_id'. This is currently they way I have built it but for some reason it feels like it might screw me over in the future (not that option one doesn't give me the same feeling). So my question is which way do you guys recommend or is there maybe a different better way that I could be doing this?

Comment: Option 2 is the right way to go.  SQL is not designed to put lists of things into comma delimited strings.  It is designed to put lists of things into a table.

Comment: Option 3: use separate table for `Tasks` and separate table for `TaskAssignees`, where the second table will act as pivot between `Tasks` and `Users` tables.

Comment: @tereško thats what I ended up doing

Answer (score 1):

Option 2 ist the better solution since you can acutally work with the table. You may e.g. create another table `Tasks` with

```
Task_id    |  Task_name   |  Budget  | ...
```

Or a table with user-IDs for `assigned_to` and  `assigned_from`. All these tables can be joined together if you use 2nd Option.

btw it is the correct [normalization form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: what about having a many to many type relationship with a user_task pivot table?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Option 2 and normalize further if tasks are always assigned by/from the same person.

`Tasks` table:

```
task_id   |   assigned_from
1         |   4
2         |   2
```

The `Assignees` table then doesn't need to have the `assigned_from` since it's always the same for that `task_id`:

```
id   |   task_id   |   assigned_to
1    |   1         |   1
2    |   1         |   3
3    |   1         |   6
4    |   2         |   1
5    |   2         |   4
```